# laravel s3 signed url does not work with pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, amazon-s3, public, sign

I have recently added s3 as a storage to my laravel application. I use signed url which works perfectly with uploaded images, but it does not with pdfs. I receive access denied, for the pdfs. If I make the files public via S3 console, I can receive it.
I am uploading these files with this mehtid:
`Storage::disk('s3')->put();`

I have tried signing the url with these two methods:

```
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl(
        $path, Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)
    );

 $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
 $client = $s3->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();
 $expiry = "+10 minutes";

 $command = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => \Config::get('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
        'Key'    => $path,

    ]);

 $request = $client->createPresignedRequest($command, $expiry);

 return (string) $request->getUri();
```

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.
The problem was, when I gave the url to pdf.js, it automatically changed "&" chars in the url to "&" , and s3 didnt recognize this url. I solved it using js string replace method

```
  var pdfUrl = '{{\App\Models\DataHelper::getImgUrl($note->file)}}'; //getting the singed url
  pdfUrl = pdfUrl.replaceAll("&amp;", '&');
  showPDF(pdfUrl); //pdf.js
```